# Login form via Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the Devise gem currently installed and am using it for autheraization for my webapp.

I have the login/logout links on my front page thus..

```
<ul class="user_nav">
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <li>Signed in as <%= current_user.email %> | <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete ) %></li>
                <% else %>
                <li> <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path, :id => 'login') %>  | <%= link_to('Create an account', new_user_registration_path, :id => "create") %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
```

I'm trying to utilize the Twitter-Bootstrap Modal feature so put my login form inside a separate box that would show up when the user clicks on it.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses Simpleform

```
    #Modal
    <div class="modal" id="loginModal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Sign in</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name),:html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
                <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
                <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
                <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn' %>
            <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    #link
    <%= link_to('Login', "#loginModal", :id => 'login', "data-toggle" => "modal") %> 

    #javascript
    $('#loginModal').modal(options)
```